# how to integrat bloc pattern with a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, bloc

So recently I am trying to integrate bloc pattern inside my already built app
I started at the login page where i have two textfields for gsm and password
I add the bloc package to the yaml file and installed the plugin bloc
Then started with gsm field creating a bloc for it
Then i realized that for the password I need another bloc
And if i dive into sign up page I may need four or five blocs
Is that the normal behavior or it may affect the performance and smoothness of the app  and is there a better way using the bloc pattern ...
is it better to build the bloc pattern from scratch using streams and sinks I already tried this and also created a provider like below :

```
    class Provider extends InheritedWidget {
  final bloc = Bloc();

  Provider({Key key, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_) => true;

  static Bloc of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Provider>() as Provider)
        .bloc;
  }
}
```

but stuck of how to add more than one bloc in order to make the app more modular and readable and if I need to create a provider for each bloc or not,any help on this side also ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a provider for each bloc. Your Provider class is an `InheritedWidget`, so redundant use of it might cause performance issues. It's already possible to access all your blocs through a single Provider.

#### Provider

All blocs are in your Provider class:

```dart
class Provider extends InheritedWidget {
  final gsmBloc = GsmBloc(); // Bloc 1
  final passwordBloc = PasswordBloc(); // Bloc 2
  // add more ...

  Provider({
    Key key,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_) => true;

  static Provider of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Provider>()!;
  }
}
```

#### MyApp

Initialize Provider in your first widget (or beforehand in case you want to access it here):

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Bloc Pattern',
      home: Provider(
        child: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### MyHomePage

Access your blocs through Provider using the nearest context:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Access your blocs through Provider
    final passwordBloc = Provider.of(context).passwordBloc;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar('Flutter Bloc Pattern'),
      body: Center(
         child: Text('My Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you dear , I really was about to do this but I thought it may be a better way, thanks again I gonna apply the methodology and about the other question is using this way better and more scalable than using the flutter bloc packge